# How do you find the right English words?

Tags: single-word-requests

An example, just a minute ago I was looking for a word to replace *candidate*

*Amongst the candidates for the album title.*

since the *candidate* is a person, not the one-of-many album titles.

So, I was wondering. When faced with a problem as such, where do you go to look for a certain word, if you cannot remember it / do not know it?

Comment: you could try a thesaurus or dictionary.

Comment: Candidate can be a person but it can also be a thing, according to the [first dictionary I checked](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/candidate): "3. a person or thing regarded as suitable or likely for a particular fate or position ⇒ this wine is a candidate for his cellar". // Tip: "English" is spelled with a capital E.

Comment: @Hugo - My mistake. Rectified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *candidate* doesn't have to be a person. When you have questions like this, you can try an online thesaurus, such as http://thesaurus.com/

Answer (score 1):

Thesaurus.net has this wordfinder functionality where you can search for a synonym for "candidate" and it provides a word web with words related to "candidate". You just need to click each word in order to find out whether the word almost fit with your idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer

[Replacement word of candidate](http://thesaurus.com/browse/candidate)